# Parsing through string to create an array of objects, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am returning an array of objects that contain a string. I want to parse through the string and create a new object whenever the string has a pipe.

Here is an example of the array

```
[
    {
        list : {
            category : '(noun)',
            synonyms : 'order|war (antonym)'
        }
    }, {
        list : {
            category : '(noun)',
            synonyms : 'harmony|concord|concordance'
        }
    }, {
        list : {
            category : '(noun)',
            synonyms : 'peacefulness|peace of mind|repose|serenity|heartsease|ataraxis|tranquillity|tranquility|quietness|quietude'
        }
    }, {
        list : {
            category : '(noun)',
            synonyms : 'public security|security'
        }
    }, {
        list : {
            category : '(noun)',
            synonyms : 'peace treaty|pacification|treaty|pact|accord'
        }
    }
]
```

I am looping through this with a for loop and getting data[i].list.synonyms but this returns a string like 'peace treaty|pacification|treaty|pact|accord'

How do I parse through this and get all 5 synonyms into their own object?

Thanks a lot

Comment: To get an array use `data[i].list.synonyms.split('|')`

Comment: perfect! I thought I tried that. I must of had a space. Thanks a lot @tushar

Comment: There is nothing here related to "parsing", which means to analyze text according to some grammar. I suppose you mean "accessing a string" or "converting a string".

Answer (score 0):

Use [data[i].list.synonyms.split("|")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). It will return an array of the strings that were separated by whatever character you pass to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.prototype.split`.

For example, this snippet modifies your object in such way that it now contains an array of synonyms:

```js
// Your object:
var obj = [
    { list : { category : '(noun)', synonyms : 'order|war (antonym)' } }, 
    { list : { category : '(noun)', synonyms : 'harmony|concord|concordance' } }, 
    { list : { category : '(noun)', synonyms : 'peacefulness|peace of mind|repose|serenity|heartsease|ataraxis|tranquillity|tranquility|quietness|quietude' } }, 
    { list : { category : '(noun)', synonyms : 'public security|security' } }, 
    { list : { category : '(noun)', synonyms : 'peace treaty|pacification|treaty|pact|accord' } }
];

// Modification
obj.forEach(function(x) {
  x.list.synonyms = x.list.synonyms.split('|');
});

// Demonstration purposes only:
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4) + "</pre>"
```

Comment: `map` is better candidate here than `forEach`. `arr.map(function(e) {
    e.list.synonyms = e.list.synonyms.split('|');
    return e;
});`